# Trouble with vim line completion?

Tags: autocompletion

Completion seems to work ok overall (so `<C-X>` + `<C-]>` complete for tags and `<C-X>` + `<C-N>`/`<C-P>` complete in context), but the line completion (`<C-X>` + `<C-L>`) always tells me "Pattern not found".

It does not work even when at the beginning of a new line (when `<C-X>` + `<C-L>` should just copy the previous line).

UPDATE:
Even when starting vim without anything (`vim -u NONE`) line completion still does not work. huh?

Comment: What's the result of `:verbose imap <c-x><c-l>`? (should be "no mapping found")

Comment: @VanLaser it says "no mapping found" so that is not the problem.

Comment: Could you clarify what you *think* should happen when doing `<C-x><C-l>` in insert mode? Also, what is the output of `:set complete?`?

Comment: @VanLaser I think it should be `:verbose imap <ctrl-x><ctrl-l>`

Comment: @romainl I was expecting what it said on this page under "Example": http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Line/word/file/whatever_completion and my completion settings are `],i,d`

Comment: Do you have any lines *actually written* in your buffer, or you delete them all before trying?

Comment: Ah, you're missing the `.` from the 'complete' option. The current buffer *isn't* scanned. See `:h 'complete'` (with the quotes). Just leave that option alone (don't set it yourself anywhere), or *add* to it.

Comment: @VanLaser not exactly sure what you mean, but at first I tried using line completion while editing some code, so there were lots of lines. After that did not work I tried it on just 2-3 in a new file, but that also failed.

Comment: @VanLaser yes that was it, thanks! so if you add your as an answer I will mark it as solved. Although reading the `:h 'complete'` it says that `i` option scans the current file, meaning that its not the buffer? (i.e. stuff not yet written to disk?)

Comment: It was @romainl the one who asked the right question. About `i` - try it and see how it works (save the file, then `<c-x><c-l>`, without `b` complete flag set).

Comment: I… was about to write a proper answer but it was time for our weekly team meeting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `'complete'` option tells Vim where to look for building the popup menu when you do `<C-n>`, `<C-p>` and `<C-x><C-l>`.

Your value, `],i,d` means that Vim will look in tags files (`]`) and includes (`i` and `d`) for completion.

I'm sorry to say that the explanation of what `i` does is misleading and has been for a long time: it doesn't scan the current file *at all*.

If Vim doesn't see a `tags` file and doesn't find any include declaration in your buffer (or they point to files that can't be found) it has nothing to draw completions from and… simply doesn't do completion at all.